# Determine numerical infinity for Schrodinger equation $−\psi''(x) + x^ 2 \psi(x) = E\psi(x)$

Tags: numerical-analysis, ode, boundary-conditions, eigenvalues, runge-kutta

Consider the following Schrodinger equation for the harmonic oscillator with real $x$:
$$
−ψ''(x) + x^ 2 ψ(x) = Eψ(x).
$$

I solve the last equation using shooting method and implicit Runge-Kutta integration. For the eigenvalue $E=1$, the corresponding eigenfunction looks like:

[image]

where I set $x=4$ as $+∞$ and $x=-4$ as $-∞$ . From the Fig, we see that the eigenfunction exponentially decay at $x=\pm 4$ .

However, when eigenvalue $E=17$, the corresponding eigenfunction is too complicated so that it won't exponentially decays at $x=\pm 4$ as shown on the following Fig.
[image]

In fact, the eigenfunction decays at $x=\pm 6$ as shown on the following Fig.
[image]

**My Question**

The numerical infinity should be large (like $x=6$) for large eigenvalue $E$, and small (like $x=4$) for small eigenvalue. If independent from the eigenvalue, I uniformly set numerical infinity as a very large number, it would waste computational resource. So, is there any formula to determine the exact numerical infinity based on different inputted eigenvalue please?

Comment: What do you call "decaying"? What is the right threshold for it? 1/10, 1/100, 1/1000... The exact numerical infinity is at inifinity, because that is the domain of the problem. On the other hand, how do you know the eigenvalues beforehand?

Comment: The eigenvalue can be analytically calculated with results: $E = 1, 3, 5, 7...$. I am sorry that due to low reputation, I only upload two figures. Now from the 3rd Fig, the eigenfunction is decayed in the sense that the derivative of the eigenfunction with respect to $x$ at the numerical infinity is almost zero.

Comment: The eigenvectors can be analytically calculated as well.

Comment: I know it. However, my question is to ask determining the numerical infinity, rather than analytical solution.

Comment: You are not telling what threshold is good for you. You want to approximate the solution with a compact support function, but you are not providing enough information.

Comment: There is no solid or analytical threshold. The "soft" or numerical threshold can be set as (the magnitude of derivative at the numerical infinity) = 1.0E-06. This numerical threshold is just my intuition or imagination. That is all the information I have.  Haha

Comment: If you don't have a criterion for it, you can't expect that a different person tell you how to do it. I would say that a good approach is to start with a fixed size, let's say $x\in[-1,1]$ and solve it. Then double the size and compare the solution assuming that $\psi(x) = 0,\; \forall x \notin [-1,1]$. If they are in the acceptable error then the first interval was ok, if not, repeat the process.

Comment: Your assumption that $\psi(x) $ vanishes for all $x$ between the boundaries does not make sense. And, by the way, actually, there is an analytical threshold, which is $\psi'(x) = 0$ on the infinity.

Comment: Please don't [cross post](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1747687/144053).

Comment: My question is interdisciplinary between computational science and mathematics. People in the forum know mathematics may not know much about computational science;  People in the forum know computational science may not know much about mathematics. To obtain a complete and insightful answer, posting it in both forums is necessary.

Comment: Crossposting is discouraged. See [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu). I am not a mathematician, but a lot of people in SciComp are... so I think that your claim is quite incorrect.

Comment: Wow, my last response got deleted without any notification. Welcomes the unknown web administrator to delete my response. However, it's really impolite to delete my response without giving me any specific reason and notification. So I re-post my last deleted response on the following [**place**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278460/321719) . Thank you!

Comment: @Pig:  You can post ***similar*** questions on different sites, but not the ***exact*** same question on different sites.  Surely, a single question may overlap several fields (e.g. computational science & mathematics), but separate questions must be posted on each site, with each question specifically tailored to the audience.  You can edit this question to focus more on numerics / algorithms, while your math SE post can emphasize mathematical analysis/proofs pertaining to your question.  But posting the exact same question is very much discouraged, for a myriad of reasons.

Comment: @Paul: If you check the two posts I posted on the different sites, they have different titles and different contents. In the Math site, I treat $$−ψ''(x) + x^ 2 ψ(x) = Eψ(x). $$ as a special case associated with the more general case $$ −ψ''(z) − (iz)^ N ψ(z) = Eψ(z). $$. The latter equation emphasizes the use of Complex Analysis. Anyway, thank you for sharing your opinions with me. In future, I will take extra care on my posts! Regards!

Answer (score 3):

You look at the question the wrong way. First, let us consider the *exact* problem and its solution:
$$
  -\psi''(x) + x^2 \psi(x) = E\psi(x),
$$
with boundary values $\psi(\pm\infty)=0$. Now you want to consider truncating your domain somewhere, i.e., you want to consider a *different* problem that reads
$$
  -\tilde\psi''(x) + x^2 \tilde\psi(x) = E\tilde\psi(x),
$$
with boundary values $\tilde\psi(\pm x_\infty)=0$ where $x_\infty$ is a *finite* termination point of your domain.

Clearly, these two problems will have different answers, $\psi$ and $\tilde\psi$. The question you are asking is, in essence, how large you have to choose $x_\infty$. But this cannot be answered without also saying how small you want the *difference* $\psi-\tilde\psi$ to be!

If you choose $x_\infty$ small, then you can solve the problem of course, but $\psi-\tilde\psi$ will be large. On the other hand, if you want the difference to be small, you will likely have to choose $x_\infty$ to be large. In general, if you require that $\|\psi-\tilde\psi\|\le\varepsilon$, then there will be some value $\bar x(\varepsilon)$ so that any $x_\infty\ge \bar x(\varepsilon)$ will be a valid choice of the domain size.

Comment: If I understand your answer correctly, you suggest that I need numerically solve two equations simultaneously - the original equation and the complex conjugate of the original equation - afterwards, I compare the difference $\psi(x) - \bar \psi(x)$ from the two solutions at the chosen numerical infinity $x_\infty$. If the difference is not vanished, then I have to increase the chosen value for $x_\infty$ and numerically solve the two equations simultaneously again. Then do the comparison again. I think that your method may work, but numerically it is expensive. Anyway, I give you +1.

Comment: No, no, you misunderstand. $\bar\psi$ isn't the complex conjugate (I should have chosen a different notation, maybe $\tilde\psi$). It's just the solution of a different problem, on a finite domain, whereas $\psi$ is the solution on the infinite domain. Of course, numerically, you can't solve for $\psi$ because -- well -- the domain is *infinite*.

Comment: I've edited the answer to use $\tilde\psi$ instead of $\bar\psi$.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification! Looks like I need to do the following things: After numerically calculating $\tilde \psi(x)$, then due to exponentially decay (i.e. $ \psi'(\infty) = 0$), $\tilde \psi'(x_\infty)$ must be vanished as well. Numerically, I can set $\tilde \psi'(x_\infty) < \epsilon $. If the last inequality is not satisfied, then I must increase $x_\infty$, then solve the ODE again and find the new solution $\tilde \psi(x)$ until the last inequality is satisfied. All looks well, except that I may never find $\tilde \psi(x)$ at first hand due to incorrect selection of $x_\infty$.

Comment: The Runge-Kutta integration may not guarantee to converge if $x_\infty$ is not appropriately chosen. If it's not converged, then $\tilde \psi(x)$ can not be obtained, consequently there is no way to do the following test $\tilde \psi'(x_\infty) < \epsilon$. But thank you for your answer!

Comment: Yes, your algorithm makes sense. And indeed, you will never find the *exact* solution. But that is no different than trying to solve a PDE on a *finite* interval either: you can make the mesh size as small as you want, all you can ever hope is to come *arbitrarily close* to the solution, but you will never find it.

Answer (score 2):

You should maybe look at the analytical form of these solutions [(here's the wikipedia page)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator), this would probably help you to derive a relation between the energy level $n$ and the typical length of your state (I would look at the $H_n$ functions given in the link above).

Comment: It would be much better to determine the length of my state without knowing the analytical form. However, I give you +1, since your answer implies that I should look at asymptotic solution for the eigenfunctions. The asymptotic form must provide information where $\psi'(x)$ and $\psi(x)$ vanishes on the $x$.